# How to solve the issue when running session to get 'static' shape of a tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using session to get the 'static' shape of a tensor based on the command 'tf.shape()'. The shape of the tensor 'deconv4.outputs' is [16,256,256,3] and I want to obtain the first dimension of 'deconv4.outputs' by using 'tf.shape()'. However, I got an error message when running 'tf.shape()' in session:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'FRUC_DVF_g/deconv4/b_conv2d': Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
```

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks!

The shape of the tensor 'deconv4.outputs' is [16,256,256,3].

```
deconv4 = Conv2d(deconv3_bn_relu, 3, [5, 5], act=tf.tanh, padding='SAME', W_init=w_init, name='deconv4')

    #################### Calculate Voxel Flow based on the 'deconv4' ############################
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(tf.shape(deconv4.outputs)[0]))
```

The expected result is that the 'tf.shape()' returns '16'

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks like your code explicitly assigns this operation to a gpu, but your machine only provides a cpu device. Tensorflow allows you to assign operations to gpu/cpu devices explicitly for optimizing the computation, check [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu) for more info.

To solve this problem, you could try setting `tf.Session(..., allow_soft_placement=True)` in the tf.Session constructor, which makes tensorflow choose any available device automatically in case an explicitly assigned device is not available.